# Setting min/max/interval for Y axis in a WinRTXamlToolkit Chart

Tags: charts, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit, windows-8.1-universal

How do I set the minimum/maxium/interval on the y axis on the chart - `ColumnSeries`?
I'm using the `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting` lib in a Windows 8.1 Store app.

The chart works fine without, but if I attempt to set `Minimum`, `Maximum` or `Interval` it fails with following error: "Cannot assign to nullable type on property Minimum"

```
<charting:Chart
    x:Name="BarChart2"
    Height="400"
    Title="title"
    Margin="0,0">
    <charting:ColumnSeries                      
        ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Initials}"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding NumberOfVisits}"
        IsSelectionEnabled="True"  >                        
        <charting:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
            <charting:LinearAxis
                Orientation="Y"
                Interval="1"
                Minimum="2"
                ShowGridLines="False"/>
        </charting:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
    </charting:ColumnSeries>
</charting:Chart>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in code using something like this:

```
                    ((LineSeries)LineChart.Series[0]).DependentRangeAxis = new LinearAxis()
                {
                    Maximum = 50,
                    Minimum = 30,                        
                    Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y,
                    Interval = 20,
                    ShowGridLines = true,
                };
```